# Modify the content of an MS Word file contained inside a .zip file, without extracting it?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, zip

Is it possible to manipulate the content of an MS Word file contained inside a .zip file, without extracting it?

I have 2,000 zip files containing Word files.  I need to modify the same field in each of the 2,000 zipped MS Word files.  Is this possible without extracting the file first?

Comment: It depends... If you use a library it would have to support transparently editing files, otherwise no. IMHO extract the file to a temp directory, make changes and then put the edited file back into the archive. Are you concerned with freezing, locking, then theres a way around this. Why would you not want to extract them?

Comment: Hi @Codexer I was trying to minimise the number of steps I had to execute and therefore limit the number of potential failure points.  I was surprised my searches yielded no results, but if it has to be an extract, manipulate, overwrite in .zip then so be it.  Thanks...

Comment: Look at the [ZipArchiveEntry.Open Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but the difference is semantics. When I do this, with single documents, I COPY (not extract) the xml file from the zip container, edit as required, and then OVERWRITE back into the zip container.

I've also tried to edit the file from within the zip file, but it can't be saved directly (at least not the way I have tried) - so (for example in NotePad++) file SaveAs would be required...